# Single signon using WP database

Tags: wordpress

I have a SaaS application/widget, which people can add to their website via an iframe. Is it possible to use wordpress as a single signon point, so that people who login at a wordpress site, are also logged in at my widget? Like a bridge of some sort.

Comment: You could have the widget login table look at WP's, granted you have access to both,

Comment: However, i doubt that people who use my widget will allow me direct access to their Wp database. So i was looking for a bridge or api, such as facebook's oAuth, but for wordpress.

Comment: Oh sorry, I read it incorrectly. Dont think that's possible due to security